# Unable to stub GetStream API for testing purposes

Tags: getstream-io

I'm trying to write some unit tests for some functions that use the stream API. I'd like to stub out the stream API using something like Sinon:

```
sinon.stub(stream.feed, 'get');
```

This would work except that `stream.connect()` throws an error when I connect in a test environment.

```
You are publicly sharing your App Secret. Do not expose the App Secret in browsers, "native" mobile apps, or other non-trusted environments.
```

What confuses me is that this is still client side code, I'm not exposing my App Secret key to any browser... Any ways around this?

Comment: Hey, you should try `stream.connect(apiKey, null, appId);`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Comment: Happy to help out!

Comment: @NickParsons can you explain what does this do?